# 301 redirect old indexed URLs

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

My client had a wordpress blog at "domain.com/blog" with permalink structure "?p=page-id". I archived this site at "v1.domain.com". everything works fine.

I create the new wordpress blog at "domain.com/blog" with permalink structure "/year/month/postname". still, everything fine.

I did a google search and found the old blog posts. they link to "domain.com/blog?p=page-id" and when single.php tries to open these files the loop goes crazy.

here is an example: 
http://davidapuzzo.com/blog/?p=1821

if you add "v1" to the beginning of the domain, you will see where the post actually is:

http://v1.davidapuzzo.com/blog/?p=1821

I understand It would be a 301 redirect that finds all "http://domain.com/blog?p=page-id" URLs and redirect/prepends them with "v1.domain.com..." ? I just dont know how to write the reg expression and where to add it within my wordpress .htaccess file.

**I've included my wordpress .htaccess below:**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

My client has some deep indexed URLs, as you can see above with the Connecticut Weatherman/Meterologist. that post is the 6th result on the first page of results for a search on his name.

The new site was launched today and any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Redirect anything with **?p=###** to the v1 domain?

Comment: exactly, jon. virendra's updated code below has solved the problem well.  is there another solution you would suggest? I'm not certain how the code can be improved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^davidapuzzo.com
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p= [NC]
RewriteRule blog/(.*)$ http://v1.davidapuzzo.com/blog/ [L,R=301]
```

To redirect all URLs containing a query string to the sub-domain use the following. This will redirect all URL containing '?'.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^davidapuzzo.com
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule blog/(.*)$ http://v1.davidapuzzo.com/blog/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I just realized, there is an error in the code, let me rewrite the rule until that you should comment out these htaccess rules.

Comment: had to change "v11" to "v1" , but is working now. thanks! in addition to the blog posts, there are a ton of other pages that I'd like redirected, all in the format "http://davidapuzzo.com/blog/?[page]" where [page] is usually [page_id=#], [cat=#], [p=#]. Is there an easy update to the code you provided to include these as well?

Comment: additionally, I have "http://v1.davidapuzzo.com/blog/" disallowed via robots.txt -- if I 301 redirect all the old indexed references, will they eventually disappear from rankings?

Comment: ok, i'll update the answer. You want to redirect anything in /blog/ or only specific urls? Also, do you want to also redirect http://davidapuzzo.com/blog/ to http://v1.davidapuzzo.com/blog/

Comment: You will have to allow robots to crawl your new sub-domain else, they won't be able to rank your site, and may eventually result in removing the site, although not necessary.

Comment: I want to redirect specific URLs. "davidapuzzo.com/blog/?[string]" to "v1.davidapuzzo.com/blog/?[string]" essentially, anything in the /blog/ with a question mark at the end.

Comment: regarding "v1.davidapuzzo.com" sub-domain -- I dont want search engines to crawl the site, that's why I've disallowed. It is the old website and I've only moved it there for archive purpose. I want to 301 redirect the above URL's because they are currently linking to pages that don't exist in the new permalink structure on "davidapuzzo.com/blog/". I'm only curious if they will disappear now that I am 301 redirecting them to a disallowed domain? which would be perfectly fine with me.

Comment: Those URLs might disappear but one cannot be very sure about that. Also, will your new URL structure never contain any query string?

Comment: regarding query string. yes, the new structure will never use query strings. it uses a natural language permalink/URL structure based on year/month/post-titles/

Comment: I have updated the answer to redirect any URL containing a query string.

Comment: that will do it. all pages are redirecting properly now. thanks so much for your help, virendra!